# Implementing IDisposable for @using in razor

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, umbraco

This is a question related to [this post](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/94198-how-to-pass-around-custom-model-along-with-the-model-from-umbracoviewpagetemplatepage) (which is also made by me)

All the explanation of the website I'm creating is in the link above. Please see it there.

That being said, I'm trying to have two models of different types within a razor, and I'm having difficulty properly dealing with the directives, (@using @inherits, and all that)
and I get errors saying it failed to bind my custom made model to the one that is created by the CMS (UmbracoTemplateView).

In the course of thinking how to circumvent this, I came up with assigning @using directive for IPublishedContent, thus something like below.
This way, the UmbracoTemplateView should be assigned to a variable with a much narrower scope, meaningI should be able to avoid triggering that error.

```
@model CodeShare.Library.Models.SearchViewModel
@using CodeShare.Web.Controllers


<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">

        <!--this part uses UmbracoTemplatePage to render the content dynamically-->


        @using (UmbracoTemplatePage)
        {

            var pageSize = 5;
        IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> newsPosts = Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.DescendantOrSelf("news").Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.DocumentTypeAlias ==     "newsPost").OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdateDate);
            var page = 1; int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["p"], out page);
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)newsPosts.Count() / (double)pageSize);

            if (page > totalPages)
            {
                page = totalPages;
            }
            else if (page < 1)
            {
                page = 1;
            }

        }

        @foreach (var item in newsPosts.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))
        {
            var imagid = item.GetPropertyValue("image");
            string imgurl = Umbraco.Media(imagid.ToString()).Url;

            <a href="@item.Url" class="media">
                <img src="@imgurl">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">@item.Name</h5>
                    <span>最終更新日: @item.UpdateDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") </span>
                </div>
            </a>
            }


    </div>
```

From here I want to use the custom model, because the input will made by the user not in the backoffice.

in my understanding, with this beginform method below, it sends those HiddenFor's as a set of parameters to the method called "SubmitSearchForm" in a controller class called "SurfaceController"

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitSearchForm", "Surface", new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "carousel",
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,

    }))



        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DocTypeAliases)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FieldPropertyAliases)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PageSize)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PagingGroupSize)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTerm)

    }
    <button id="submit-button">Search</button>


    <div class="carousel">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("RenderSearchResults", "Surface", new { Model = Model.SearchResults });}
    </div>

    }
```

The only change from the one I posted on our.umbraco is @using directive when trying to render from the model, which is of "UmbracoTemplateView".

Here, I'm receiving an error saying the directive that can be assigned to the @using directive here must be of the type "IDisposable" and UmbracoTemplateView is not.

I understand what is meant by the error:
UmbracoTemplateView is not a native type from .NET thus needs to be clearly specified when it can be disposed of to signal at the garbage collector. How can I assign this interface?

========================================================================

### added on 18/10/2018

I separated these two views in different cshtml's but I'm having the same problem at a higher level (should I call this node)

So when I display the page, it will be delegated like
"WebBase.cshtml"=>"Home.cshtml" => "Parts that need UmbracoTemplateView(in cshtml)" & "Parts that need custom model(in cshtml)" ....

```
//I get an error when I put the following two in the same cshtml
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@model CodeShare.Library.Models.SearchViewModel

@using CodeShare.Web.Controllers
@using ClientDependency.Core.Mvc





@{
    Layout = "WebBase.cshtml";
}

@* the fun starts here *@

@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/Home/.....cshtml");}
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/Home/....cshtml");}
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/Home/.....cshtml");}

<!-- only this "news" part requires custom model by Mr.Paul -->
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/Home/_News.cshtml");}

@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/Home/....cshtml");}
```

As such at some point I am going to need two models of different types in one place anyway

Comment: If you want to use two different models (maybe a custom and CodeShare models), the easiest thing you can do is to isolate some of your code in a partial view and use the model you desire there. then pass the partial view in your main view along with its model while your main view is using a different one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. 

I tried to do according to your suggestion, I've got the same kind error again. 
I believe it is because when the website is called, there are some "Html.RenderPartial" that want UmbracoTemplateView, and some other that want another model (Paul's custom "CodeShare" model)

Comment: Yes, read my comment again. You have to separate your models. Keep only one 'using' (or inherits) in your main view. Then isolate the code that needs different models in different partials. That will solve it. All in all if you need two models of different types in one place as you said, you're just doing it the wrong way. If in a partial view you're inheriting from 'UmbracoTemplatePage' or UmbracoViewPage you can use @Html.partial("partialViewName"), there's no need to pass a model. In your update I see you're trying to use renderPartial without passing a model. That won't work.

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a try some time later again (the minimal requirement for the usre input for this specific website is the page (such as ?page=3) so I decided to work on AJAX pagination first...
Thank you for your comment nonetheless!